# how to get groups from dataframe when all 1s in flag column and keep group with size greater than 2

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

i want to extract groups where flag is consective 1 , and keep group if size is greater than 2

```
here is my df :
df2=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,20,40,45,56,1,20,40,45,56],'flag':[3,2,4,1,1,3,3,1,1,1]})
print(df2)
    A  flag
0   1     3
1  20     2
2  40     4
3  45     1
4  56     1
5   1     3
6  20     3
7  40     1
8  45     1
9  56     1

output
7  40     1
8  45     1
9  56     1
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches. You and use inbuilt functions of pandas like groupby and where or simply use the below.

```
print(df2[(df2['flag']==1) & (df2['A']>2)])
```

Comment: According to your output modify in the condition as `df2['A'] > 20`.

Comment: sorry , i think you misunderstand , consective 1 groupsize should be 1

Answer (score 0):

One way using `pandas.DataFrame.groupby`:

```
s = df2["flag"].eq(1)
m = s.diff(1).ne(0).cumsum()
new_df = df2[s.groupby(m).transform(lambda x: x.sum()>2)]
```

Output:

```
    A  flag
7  40     1
8  45     1
9  56     1
```

Comment: each group shoud be in list , i need splitted groups of consective 1 with size greater than 2